# Fake Font-Icon with CSS and a PNG

Tags: css, png, font-face, mask

I have a transparent, grey-scale PNG of an icon. I want to be able to change it's color like a font-icon.

A few more details: The PNGs have outer transparencies and inner white areas for the actual "icon", plus a small greyscale gradient so they have good-looking "fuzzy" edges. I'm armed with Image Magic, so I don't mind if I have to take negatives / otherwise perform transformations on the PNG prior to any solution.

Why I can't just use a font-icon set: We have some custom, proprietary icons we're using, and I've spend hours trying to convert them to a font-icon set with no success. So I'm unlikely to find *our* icons out there, and I can't get our icons into a font-icon set. I could be doing it wrong, or I could have no found the right tool.

So my next best bet looks to be using CSS "Masking", only I can't get that work. The idea would be to set the background of the div to the correct color, and then mask out the div so only the part that corresponds to the icon is visible... but I can't get that working, either.

I'm open to any ideas, but my gut says the CSS stuff is the "way to go", unless there's some PNG->Font tool I haven't found.

So to reiterate: I have a greyscale PNG with transparency, and I need to show it on a website with a "font-color" set by CSS.

Any ideas?
(Thanks!)

Comment: Comment on your downvote.

Comment: [This Web Designer Depot Tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/) On creating font icons seems pretty straightforward if you have the ability to export SVG. I honestly don't think CSS will be the way to go because it feels to me like it'll get hairy fast. I would suggest using an editor like [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) in conjunction with [a tutorial like this](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/) to make SVG's and then turn them into a font. Wish I could help more, but this isn't my forte.

Comment: What was your process for converting the icons to an icon font?

Comment: We tried using a tool to convert them to an SVG so we could use Icomoon, but the resulting SVGs didn't look right (missing visual elements, harsher lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using masking for that isn't hard:

```
.filtered {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(http://i35.tinypic.com/2091450.png); 
    mask-size: 100% 100%;
    mask-image: url(http://i35.tinypic.com/2091450.png); 
}
```

But you won't get much support for old browsers

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qE8s/)

Comment: It's gonna take me a day or two to confirm things.

Comment: I'm not sure *why* what I was doing wasn't working before, but it's definitely working now. Thanks!

Comment: FYI for future folks: Using imagemagick, inverting the colors was easy: `convert image1.png -negate image1_mask.png` - as where the mask is black you get your "under" image showing through.